# Probability of obtaining expected result

Tags: probability

If I toss 2 coins then I expect 1 head on average, but of course I could get 0, 1 or 2 heads. The probability that I get exactly the expected number of heads is 1/2 or 50%.

Now consider a larger number of outcomes. If I toss 6 dice then I expect that one will show a six. But there could be any number of sixes from 0 to 6 inclusive. The probability of obtaining exactly the expected number is $5^5/6^5$ which is about 40.2%.

So increasing the number of outcomes (from coins to a dice) has reduced the chances of exactly achieving the expected result from 50% to about 40%.

What happens if the number of outcomes gets really big? e.g. suppose I toss a 1000 1000-sided dice. I would expect 1000 to show up once in the result. But what are the chances of achieving exactly this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a binomial distribution situation:

For $1000$ equally likely outcomes, the probability of getting a specified outcome exactly once in $1000$ trials is ${1000 \choose 1}\cdot (.001)\cdot(.999)^{999}=\left(\frac{999}{1000} \right)^{999}$.

More generally, if there are $n$ possible outcomes, the probability is 
$$\left(\frac{n-1}{n} \right)^{n-1}=\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{n-1}$$

This latter expression approaches $\frac1e$ because of the famous limit:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n=e^x$$